# How to get the OSM file to generate width of the streets?

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, pgrouting

I'm attempting to load osm data into a database and i've used both osm2p0 and osm2pgrouting and kept realizing I wasnt seeing anything that referenced the width of the streets.

This is important for me as I am writing a program to perform search and rescue where the size of the street is important as it can limit which vehicles can use which roads.

So I started looking in the osm.xml file and I havent see anything that references width of streets.

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:width. It says the key should be width. The key width describes the actual width of a way or other feature.

Am I missing something or is width not actually provided within the OSM.

Comment: As described by user MaM, the *width* key is correct but not present on every road.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if you look at the OSM tags in use, you will discover the [width=* tag](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:width), that can be [used for highways](http://taginfo.osm.org/keys/width#combinations), too. There are also some more tags that indicate the width of a road/way: [maxwidth](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:maxwidth), [lanes](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:lanes). All of this tags are optional and you don't should expect an global coverage...

I guess most important criteria (as present for every road) is the [road classification](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Highways) itself. But you need to take the country specific defaults into account, which is tricky and will take  a lot of research.

You might want to use [TrafficMining](http://code.google.com/p/trafficmining/) to create a custom routing profile that takes the road width into account to move your HGV vehicles. Maybe the [Humaniterian OSM Team](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/HOT) has already some experience on such technologies to assist desaster and emergency response.

Comment: I've pulled up a couple different OSM files from different cities and I've yet to see a width tag.  Is this tag only populated in certain area's?

Comment: Ok I found a lane tag in a few of the OSM's I've pulled up. However, like you said they are only on highways and not on general roads.  Have still yet to find an osm with the width tag or maxwidth.  I guess what I'll have to do is look at the roads classification like you mentioned and avoid roads like pedestrian and cycle way and try and find the average road size of streets.

Comment: Please see the link that I shared at the post above http://taginfo.osm.org/keys/width#combinations

Answer (score 1):

Jeremy - nice coincidence - I'm also working in search and rescue... Hope not in the same country (Poland) cause that means we're in concurrency.

I think trouble is somewhere else - nominal road width is in most cases enough for emergency vehicles - even such as fire trucks... Barrier often is kind of low width bridge, and that is tagged as maxwidth and other like max%.

Back to the point - you're using osm2po which is very good in case of creating road network, but it's not importing all tags such as osm2pgsql - that's why you cant see this tags in your data.

Maybe there is some way to force osm2po to import this tags also, but I was not searching since I've got both osm2po and osm2pgsql datasets in one database so I can move this tags between this two datasets using simple spatial query.

Comment: [Customizing osm2po](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53020/custom-osm2po-postprocessor-to-generate-a-node-file-and-a-way-file) means coding, not sure about osm2pgrouting. You might want to ask at stackexchange or help.osm.org instead.

Comment: I've used both osm2po and osm2pgrouting to ingest data into a test database.  osm2po creates 1 table while pgrouting creates 8 along with another schema tiger and tiger_data.  The pgrouting table ways is pretty much the same as the osm2po table but there are no tables for width.

My area of interest could be any where in the world and my vehicles can be as large as military RHINO's IE not average rescue vehicle size.  So i don't typically know the average road size and thus I was hoping to get it from the OSM file but saw nothing referencing it.

Comment: @Jeremy - My mistake - I was thinking about osm2pgsql and I wrote osm2pgrouting. Of course osm2pgrouting is creating sth similar to osm2po only osm2pgsql will give you full set of tags. Sorry once again.